# How can I create a matrix from several vectors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

**Consider the following MATLAB function,**

```
function m = gen_4_points()
    a = gen_const()% integer
    b = gen_const()% integer

    [x1  y1] = gen_start_point(a, b)% real
    [x2  y2] = gen_start_point(a, b)% real
    [x3  y3] = gen_start_point(a, b)% real
    [x4  y4] = gen_start_point(a, b)% real

    %r(1:4, 1:4) = 0;
    r = [   a b x1 y1 ;%int int real real 
            a b x2 y2 ;%int int real real 
            a b x3 y3 ;%int int real real
            a b x4 y4  %int int real real
        ];
    m = r;
end
```

**The resultant matrix is not my desired one.**

Vector values are OK.

But, the resultant matrix has all integer values.

> ```
> >> m  = gen_4_points();    
> a =     
>            0     
> b =    
>           -2 
> x1 =
>           -0.6766
> y1 =   
>           -2.3028
> x2 =    
>           -0.9189  
> y2 = 
>           -3.2118   
> x3 =
>            1.2869  
> y3 = 
>           -2.2803  
> x4 =  
>            1.5511 
> y4 =  
>           -2.4353 
> >> m     
> m =
>            0          -2          -1          -2
>            0          -2          -1          -3
>            0          -2           1          -2
>            0          -2           2          -2 
> >>
> ```

What is going on really?

**How can I fix the issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typecast `a` and `b` to doubles:

```
a = double(gen_const())
b = double(gen_const())
```

Comment: Hmm..... I didn't know that a MATLAB matrix cannot automatically convert int to double.

Comment: It can, but as it tries to abstract all typecasting from the user, it sometimes makes assumptions about type different from what the user expects.  In this particular case, I believe it takes the first value and sets that as matrix type.

Comment: I don't think your alternative actually works.  What happens is that the bracket `[...]` creates the array and casts to integer, and then `single(...)` re-casts - so you've already lost your precision.  You need to cast the integers to floating point first.

Comment: That's not what `typecast` does. Try `a = int32(12); b = typecast(a, 'single');`. Receive unpleasant surprise. Instead, you want to `a = single(a); b = single(b);`

Comment: Or `double`. Even going from `int32` to `single`, you're losing precision. If you're starting with an `int64`, you'll lose even more. Not sure if that's a problem in this case.